# Some images break on load

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, oop

When I run my page locally it looks like it should:

- https://ibb.co/gR1JXcq
- https://ibb.co/q9cLN04

But when I try to do the same on the Github Pages, some of the
images, not all of them, break:

https://pawelzygmuntkrol.github.io/michalkrol/ ([Repo here](https://github.com/pawelzygmuntkrol/michalkrol))

Images are optimized. The page is not hardcoded, it loops through data and returns code that displays images and text. I've tried to make images small to check if that's the problem but it doesn't help. The default size and weight doesn't seem
to have impact as well because bigger and heavier ones work while some
of the smaller ones don't. There are always the same images that are
broken. It started when I added 6 of them but as you can see even if I
add some new, some work, some don't. Should I work with asynchronous
function or some loader?

Comment: some of your images has '.JPG' some '.jpg'. perhaps this is the error?

Comment: yes its the '.JPG' problem

Comment: Linux is case-sensitive, not Windows. That's why it works locally, and not on Github